# True Memory Issue - Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Basically trying to do some **daily** user management work. User database has several thousand users (30ish) but it looks like the function struggles due to the size.

I boiled down the function as much as I could and yes, I increased the size and memory limits (540 seconds, 2 GB).

Perhaps I am doing something stupidly wrong, perhaps I need to explore a different solution like Cloud Run or App Engine or something bigger.

```
module.exports = async (data, context)  => {

  // Get all of the users in the database
  const userQuery = await db.collection('users').get()

  let authPromises = []

  userQuery.forEach(userDoc => {
    
    authPromises.push(
      admin.auth().getUser(userDoc.id).then(userResult => {
        return {
          metadata: userResult.metadata,
          ...userDoc.data().arrayOfKeysIWant
        }
      })
    )    

  })

  let authResult = await Promise.all(authPromises)

  let signInCount = 0
  authResult.forEach(user => {
    if (user.metadata.lastRefreshTime) {
      signInCount += 1
    }
  })

  console.log(signInCount)

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res({count: authResult.length, signInCount})
  })

}
```

Comment: If you _really_ need to go through every user in the database, perhaps you could do that in chunks with [a cursor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)?

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely does not scale to query all of those documents and load them all into memory at the same time.  If you have an arbitrarily large collection of documents to process individually, you should split up your queries into batches using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).  You should do a little math to figure out what a good page size, given the contents of your documents, that fits reasonably into available memory.

Comment: Thanks Doug and @cbr . I'll take a swing with the pagination/cursor. I had only ever thought of that in the client side presentation context.

Comment: So the batching resolves the memory issue however with the various API calls that need to be made, I am now timing out of the function. Any other thoughts / strategies?